# Boto3 fails to load in jupyter notebook but not in python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I know there are so many question online about this, but I havent found a solution, and what I can add into my problem is that when I check what is install in my enviroment I can see boto3 been installed

[image]

I have run the install of boto3 by doing

```
pip3 install boto3
```

and also

```
pip install boto3
```

However, when I am in Jupyter notebook, I get the error of module not found

[image]

I dont understand why when I am using the same enviroment I get this error in Jupyter notebook, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter is using a different python binary.

Can you try installing boto3 using `%pip install boto3` command from jupyter?

Or install it to your user area, run this from a terminal `pip install --user boto3`. Restart your jupyter and try importing boto3 again.

Comment: TO everyone having same issue, i took option 1 (%pip install boto3) from within jupyter notebook and worked, I did this option as from memory i tried %pip install boto3 but I can not confirm if I restart jupyter (I think i did) and didnt work, first option worked for me :)